# How to use expect to automatically enter SSH passphrase?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect

I am aware of the risks associated with this, however i still want to do it.

I have tried to follow other answers but without success.

Basically all I want is to open that ssh tunnel at boot up. So I am making a script that I can put as a **cron job at system boot**.

So far the script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn java -jar client.jar </dev/null &>/dev/null &

spawn ssh -fN -i /home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa -R 20001:localhost:22 other_user@other_host
expect "*passphrase*"
send "my passphrase\r"
```

The result I get with this is that, neither the java process keeps running (if it is even launched at all), and neither the SSH connection is kept alive (if it is even launched at all and the passphrase inserted correctly by the `send` command).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using both a key and a passphrase? What happens if you type the `ssh` command in a terminal by itself?

Comment: it asks me the passphrase. the passphrase is associated with the private key

Comment: If you are willing to script this and hardcode the passphrase in the script, why not store the key in unencrypted form? You could also create a dedicated key for that, in case you use the same key for other hosts.

Comment: @PedroD : Add `expect eof` at the last line.

Comment: cool, the ssh connection keeps working after the script finishes. However the java process is not created.

Answer (score 1):

1. For *spawn java*: Expect's `spawn` does not understand `<`, `&>` and `&`. You can use Tcl's `exec` command since you are not interacting with the Java command.

   `exec java -jar client.jar < /dev/null >& /dev/null &`
2. For *spawn ssh*: As [Dinesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974155/) pointed out, you have to add `expect eof` or it'll not wait for the `ssh` process to exit.

Comment: @pedrod, If you want to be able to type commands interactively in the ssh session, use `interact` instead of `expect eof`

Answer (score -1):

Better try **`autoexpect`**, that should work.

By using

```
 sudo yum install expect
```

or 
     sudo apt-get install expect

Once the installation is complete. type the command `autoexpect`.

It will show a message like below :

> `Autoexpect started, file is script.exp`

After this just perform the activity manually, and a script is written for you.

here is an example
[Automating-with-Expect-Scripts](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13758827)

Comment: Ok @rghome Fair Enough, here is an excerpt, install Autoexpect. By using sudo yum install expect or sudo apt-get install expect. Once the installation is complete. type the command _autoexpect_ 
It will show a message like below :

Autoexpect started, file is script.exp
After this just perform the activity manually, and a script is written for you.